# System.ServiceProcess not appearing in C# Express 2010

Tags: service, visual-c#-express-2010

I'm trying my hand at writing a service using C# 2010 Express, and I'm hitting a roadblock at the very earliest step. The System.ServiceProcess Namespace doesn't appear to exist on my computer.

Put simply, the namespace appears to be completely missing. The only System namespace starting with S that exists is System.Security. Nothing else appears in the list.

I have both .Net 3.5 and 4.0 installed on this machine. It's a company computer, and thus built to someone else's exacting standards.

Do I need to download and install Windows SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need to reference the respective assembly.

Yeah, so I looked it up:

`System.ServiceProcess` (in System.ServiceProcess.dll)